# Neo4J Collaborative Filtering Slower than Expected

Tags: neo4j, query-optimization, cypher, query-performance, collaborative-filtering

I'm working on implementing a recommendations system on top of our Neo4J graph and just started looking at the query I'm planning on using, but it's performing a lot slower than I had anticipated.

**Stats**

```
Neo4J Version: 2.3.1
Nodes: 820K
Relationships: 7.6M
```

I've looked into query optimizations quite a bit, but as far as I can see I'm not making any of the usual/common pitfalls in query structure (but I'm no expert).

Here is a dev console with a test dataset: http://console.neo4j.org/r/b7jk2b

**The Query**

```
MATCH (u1:User {id: {user_id}})-[l1:LIKES]->(p1:Product)
WITH u1, l1, p1
ORDER BY p1.created_at DESC
LIMIT 10

MATCH (p1)<-[:LIKES]-(u2:User)
WHERE NOT u1=u2
WITH u1, l1, p1, u2, COUNT(u2) as rating
ORDER BY rating DESC
LIMIT 50

MATCH (u2)-[l2:LIKES]->(recommendation:Product)
WHERE NOT (p1)=(recommendation)
WITH recommendation, COUNT(recommendation) as weight
RETURN recommendation.id as id
ORDER BY weight DESC
LIMIT {limit}
```

**Our Indexes**

```
Indexes
ON :LIKES(created_at)     ONLINE  
ON :Product(id)           ONLINE  
ON :Product(created_at)   ONLINE  
ON :User(id)              ONLINE  
ON :User(date_joined)     ONLINE

No constraints
```

**Query Profile Output** (against a copy of our production dataset)

```
+-------------------+----------------+--------+---------+--------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Operator          | Estimated Rows | Rows   | DB Hits | Identifiers                                | Other                                                   |
+-------------------+----------------+--------+---------+--------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| +ProduceResults   |              7 |    100 |       0 | id                                         | id                                                      |
| |                 +----------------+--------+---------+--------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| +Projection       |              7 |    100 |       0 | anon[382], id, recommendation, weight      | anon[382]                                               |
| |                 +----------------+--------+---------+--------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| +Top              |              7 |    100 |       0 | anon[382], recommendation, weight          | Literal(100); weight                                    |
| |                 +----------------+--------+---------+--------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| +Projection       |              7 | 129342 |  129342 | anon[382], recommendation, weight          | recommendation.id; weight                               |
| |                 +----------------+--------+---------+--------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| +EagerAggregation |              7 | 129342 |       0 | recommendation, weight                     | recommendation                                          |
| |                 +----------------+--------+---------+--------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| +Filter           |             44 | 442432 |  471953 | l1, l2, p1, rating, recommendation, u1, u2 | Ands(NOT(p1 == recommendation), recommendation:Product) |
| |                 +----------------+--------+---------+--------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| +Expand(All)      |             44 | 472039 |  472089 | l1, l2, p1, rating, recommendation, u1, u2 | (u2)-[l2:LIKES]->(recommendation)                       |
| |                 +----------------+--------+---------+--------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| +Top              |             10 |     50 |       0 | l1, p1, rating, u1, u2                     | Literal(50); rating                                     |
| |                 +----------------+--------+---------+--------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| +EagerAggregation |             10 |    527 |       0 | l1, p1, rating, u1, u2                     | u1, l1, p1, u2                                          |
| |                 +----------------+--------+---------+--------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| +Filter           |             92 |    563 |     563 | anon[82], anon[119], l1, p1, u1, u2        | Ands(NOT(u1 == u2), u2:User)                            |
| |                 +----------------+--------+---------+--------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| +Expand(All)      |             92 |    574 |     584 | anon[82], anon[119], l1, p1, u1, u2        | (p1)<-[:LIKES]-(u2)                                     |
| |                 +----------------+--------+---------+--------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| +Top              |              5 |     10 |       0 | anon[82], l1, p1, u1                       | Literal(10);                                            |
| |                 +----------------+--------+---------+--------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| +Projection       |              5 |     42 |      42 | anon[82], l1, p1, u1                       | u1; l1; p1; p1.created_at                               |
| |                 +----------------+--------+---------+--------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| +Filter           |              5 |     42 |     413 | l1, p1, u1                                 | p1:Product                                              |
| |                 +----------------+--------+---------+--------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| +Expand(All)      |              6 |    413 |     414 | l1, p1, u1                                 | (u1)-[l1:LIKES]->(p1)                                   |
| |                 +----------------+--------+---------+--------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| +NodeIndexSeek    |              1 |      1 |       2 | u1                                         | :User(id)                                               |
+-------------------+----------------+--------+---------+--------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

I've seen case-studies where people are using Neo4j to do real-time collaborative filtering, so I assumed it must be possible to get this kind of query working over this kind of dataset. Am I being unrealistic? We're running this on an Amazon EC2 Compute-Optimized node (c4.large) so I figured it would be fairly performant.

I'm left scratching my head here and would really appreciate any input.

Cheers,
David.

Comment: You might be interested in: [neo4j-fiber](https://github.com/VeliovGroup/neo4j-fiber). This package has build-in query optimisation. Here is  [example app](http://neo4j-graph.meteor.com)

Comment: How long does your query take?

Answer (score 0):

*[Aside: The dev console, when reopened, does not re-create indexes, so they have to be manually recreated.]*

I don't know if this is good enough for you, but you can eliminate about 44% of the DB hits in your profiled results by simply not specifying the labels for most of the nodes (`p1`, `u2`, and `recommendation`) in your query:

```
MATCH (u1:User {id: {user_id}})-[l1:LIKES]->(p1)
WITH u1, l1, p1
ORDER BY p1.created_at DESC
LIMIT 10

MATCH (p1)<-[:LIKES]-(u2)
WHERE NOT u1=u2
WITH u1, l1, p1, u2, COUNT(u2) as rating
ORDER BY rating DESC
LIMIT 50

MATCH (u2)-[l2:LIKES]->(recommendation)
WHERE NOT (p1)=(recommendation)
WITH recommendation, COUNT(recommendation) as weight
RETURN recommendation.id as id
ORDER BY weight DESC
LIMIT {limit}
```

The label for `u1` should still be specified in the query, since, that allows  Cypher to index on `:User(id)`. In general, one should carefully evaluate a query to see when node labels can be eliminated. In your case, the `p1`, `u2`, and `recommendation` nodes can be found by following relationships (and, I presume, the `LIKE` relationship type is only used to point to `Product` nodes), so specifying their labels is superfluous and causes unnecessary work.

The profile results for the above query will have a `DB Hits` value of `0` for all the `Filter` steps (and in one case, the `Filter` step will be eliminated entirely).

Comment: Hi cybersam,

Thanks for the feedback. I actually thought giving labels to each node made the query more targeted and improved performance :-| Glad to find out now that I was wrong in that sense.

Unfortunately we also have a relationship that is `(u:User)-[:LIKES]->(p:Shop)` which means we have to filter on the target node type. Thinking about it now though, we should probably turn the relationships into something more specific like `[:LIKES_SHOP]` to avoid that need.

You've given me food for thought. I'm going to jump back into the query and see what I can come up with.

Thanks again,
David